# How to redirect all internet traffic to local proxy in the same workstation

Tags: linux, proxy, ip, traffic

I'm trying to find a way to redirect all the internet traffic to catch all the ip packets and work with them.

For example, with my webbrowser I try to connect to www.google.com then it generates a http request, with ip packet. I want to get that packet in my machine and then do something with it.

Is there any way to do it?

(I'm working with linux OS)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to capture network traffic on your own machine, try `tcpdump`. It dumps all IP packets to a file (with `-w` flag). See http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump

Comment: No I want to redirect all the traffic, and then I will transmit all this traffic into ICMP packets, and send with ping protocol to my server.

Comment: You want to encapsulate all IP traffic into ICMP packets and forward that to another server? Wow. I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: yes it is, it's a good way to jump over login acces points. It's like pingtunneling. It's for a project that I'm working out.